# Как получить доступ к .env в node?

Tags: node.js, laravel, .env

У меня вопрос про доступ к `laravel` `.env` в `node`.

Там есть библиотека `dotenv` которая должна дать доступ к `.env` файлу.

Не знаю я что то не правильно делаю, или в библиотеке не расчитано все это.

Но когда в `.env` файе не само значение а ключ к другому ключу, оно возврощает мне прямое значение.

Вот `.env` файл, и то что я получаю при запросе (`console.log(process.env.API_TOKEN)`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно не замарачиваясь решить эту проблему?

Comment: `Не знаю я что то не правильно делаю, или в библиотеке не расчитано все это.` может быть тогда стоит прочитать документацию?

Comment: @nörbörnën К вашему удевлению здесь (https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) чечего такого нету.

Comment: @nörbörnën А вот сам парсер `dotenv` `var keyValueArr = line.match(/^\s*([\w\.\-]+)\s*=\s*(.*)?\s*$/)`

Comment: итак, вы прочли документацию и исходник. какой-то вывод уже готов?

Comment: @nörbörnën Если есть мысли скажите? Парсить сомостоятельно это последний вариант.

Comment: есть 2 мысли. * библиотека dotenv не подходит для решения вашей задачи. * вы не нашли в документации ответ на вопрос. `What about variable expansion?

Try dotenv-expand`

Comment: @nörbörnën прочитал. по логике должно работать. Но почему то у меня одно и то же сейчас.
Пример вот отсюда.
`https://coderoad.ru/48781629/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5-env`